# Как переобразовать строку в массив, php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, мне приходит с $.post вот такая строка -

```
'options_cities' => '[\"1\",\"2\"][\"15\",\"16\"]'
```

Скажите, средствами php можно из нее сделать массив? На группы элементов не обращать внимание, нужны только числа.
 Вoт такого типа :

```
'options_cities' => [
            0 => '1'
            1 => '2'
            2 => '15'
            3 => '16'
        ]
```

Comment: Если объясните какая вообще связь между данными на входе и тем, что надо получить на выходе - будет предмет для обсуждения. А пока она не прослеживается.

Comment: К строке, если я не ошибаюсь можно по дефолту обращаться как к массиву.

Comment: Набор id элементов приходит как строка , мне же нужно в БД записать каждый id как отдельный

Comment: Вы показали на входе некий список значений в квадратных скобках, я вижу 4 группы скобок и как раз вы говорите что на выходе 4 элемента - ok. Но как вы скажем из `[1,7]` предлагаете получить число 86 совершено не представляю

Comment: Немного не так поставил вопрос, обновил. На скобки внимание обращать не нужно, только числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php):

```
$arr = preg_split("/[^0-9]+/", '[\"1\",\"2\"][\"15\",\"16\"]', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут 3 отличия от нормального JSON:

1. Не нужное экранирование.
2. Массивы не разделяются запятой.
3. Множество массивов лежат прямо в корне.

Примерно так:

```
$str = '[\"1\",\"2\"][\"15\",\"16\"]';

// Убираем экранирование, делим по ] и собираем уже с запятой
$str = implode('],', explode(']', str_replace("\\", '', $str)));
// ["1","2"],["15","16"],

// Помещаем в литералы массива и обрезаем лишнюю запятую в конце
$str = '[' . substr($str, 0, -1) . ']';
// [["1","2"],["15","16"]]

// Преобразуем в массив
$str = json_decode($str);
```

Но это только для входных данных примера.
Если есть другой формат, то это может не помочь.
Для этого пишут парсеры, а это просто обработка строк.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону ф-и [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), используя разделители, можно легко преобразовать строку в массив.